# word wrap, word break php html css

Tags: css

I need your help guys. I have a form and an input where i cant use word wrap, it doesnt work, here is my code: 
This is the input of the form:

```
<input value="<?php echo $ss['text']; ?>" name="text" id="" cols="30" rows="7"  class="test_input_size" >
```

$ss['text'] from sql which is "1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 11 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 11 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 11 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 11 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 11 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ......" 
and this is the class test_input_size

```
.test_input_size
{
  width:100%;
  min-height: 300px;

word-break: normal;
word-wrap: normal;
word-spacing: normal;
writing-mode: normal;
}
```

After i use word-break, word-wrap it is the same, it doesnt work even with break-all.
What should i do ?
This is a photo with how it looks like .

Comment: You missed the photo..

Comment: You're trying to use `<input>` when you should be using `<textarea>`.

Comment: if i use textarea  value="<?php echo $ss['text']; ?>" wont be displayed

Comment: i did textarea but inside the tags i put  <?php echo $ss['text']; ?> and it works now